# No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowTranslucentNavigation'

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, navigationbar

I'm trying to make the `Navigation Bar` transparent on devices with 4.4. However, the SDK does not find the resource.

Here is `res/values-v19/styles.xml` file:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="Theme.Myactionbar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
       <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
       <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Here is an image with the installed packages:

[image]

In the Manifest I have:

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

I also have tried to Clean and Build the project several times, but nothing happens.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you also change the project's **build target** to Android 4.4.2?

In `project.properties` file, or:

[image]

Comment: I am wondering why I still have the error when targetSdkVersion i set to 21.